# UltraGrid MouseDown event separate column resize from other left clicks

Tags: vb.net, infragistics, ultrawingrid

I have an infragistics ultragrid component that shows some data. One of the events that is captured is the MouseDown event. 
When the left mouse button is pressed, this could either mean that the user has selected an item, or is currently dragging the column headers.

The element is identified by use of the ElementFromPoint Method (see below). But when I resize the column header, this method will still return the first data element in the list. I need to know when the user modifies the column width as opposed to selecting or dragging an item. Is this possible at this point?

```
Private Sub ugTask_MouseDown1(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles ugTask.MouseDown

        Select Case e.Button
            Case MouseButtons.Left
                Try

                    Dim aUIElement As Infragistics.Win.UIElement = ugTask.DisplayLayout.UIElement.ElementFromPoint(New Point(e.X, e.Y))

                    m_aRow = aUIElement.GetContext(GetType(Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.UltraGridRow))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not perfect, but I found a way around this by checking the cursor type. The only time the cursor will change is when I try to resize a column. So now I can do

```
If Not cursor.Current = Cursors.Default Then
    Return
End If
```